# Struts2 - How can I call a method from Action-Bean1 if I call Action-Bean2?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, jsp, struts2, javabeans

I making a sort of action called ProfileSelector, that is loaded trought some ajax call (by using JQuery library).

This is the code :

```
// BEAN
public class ProfileSelector extends ActionSupport implements ParameterAware {
    private String profilePage;
    private Map<String, String[]> parameters;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        profilePage=getParameterValue("profilePage");
        return profilePage;
    }

    public String getParameterValue(String param) {
        if (getParameters().get(param)==null) return "main";
        return ((String[])getParameters().get(param))[0];
    }

    public Map<String, String[]> getParameters() { return parameters; }
    public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> maps) { this.parameters=maps; }

    public String getProfilePage() { return profilePage; }
    public void setProfilePage(String profilePage) { this.profilePage=profilePage; }
}

// STRUTS.XML
<action name="profile" class="model.ProfileSelector" >
    <result name="main">/profile/profile_main.jsp</result>
    <result name="edit">/profile/profile_edit.jsp</result>
    <result name="editConfirm">/profile/profile_edit.jsp</result>
    <result name="pm">/profile/profile_pm.jsp</result>
    <result name="articles">/profile/profile_articles.jsp</result>
</action>

// PAGE.JSP
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${profilePage=='edit'}">
        <s:div>
            EDIT
            <s:url id="edit" action="profile.action"><s:param name="profilePage">editConfirm</s:param></s:url>
            <sj:submit href="%{edit}" targets="profileContent" value="Edit" />
        </s:div>
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${profilePage=='editConfirm'}">
        // HERE I NEED TO LOAD A VALUE FROM ANOTHER BEAN-ACTION, not the profile one
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Looks (in the code) at **HERE I NEED TO LOAD A VALUE FROM ANOTHER BEAN-ACTION, not the profile one** : is here that i need to load (for example) a method from another Action-Bean. (example `<s:property value="someMethod" />`

How can I do it? I think is impossible with Struts, because I can call only 1 action at time. So, Interceptors? I need to change my whole structure of the application?

Let me know. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// BEAN

```
public class ListBookAction extends ActionSupport {
    BookService bookService;
    List<Book> bookList;

    public List<Book> getPostedBooks(){
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        bookList = bookService.getUserPostedBooks();
        return bookList;
    }

    public String show(){
        bookList = getPostedBooks();
        return "list";
    }
    public List<Book> getBookList() {
        return bookList;
    }
    public void setBookService(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }
}
```

//STRUTS.XML

```
        <action name="*ListBook" class="com.example.ListBookAction" method="{1}">
            <result name="list"  type="tiles-defs">listbook.listbook</result>
        </action>
```

//From browser

```
http://localhost:8888/showListBook.action
```

P.S: If you familiar with Struts 1, it work like DispatchAction.

Answer (score 1):

There is something incorrect as you never want to goto 2 different actions for anything. There is no way to do so. However, you might be able to make an ajax call from the jsp and point to different action and load the value out.

Comment: That's i don't understand on Struts2 : is not a really MVC. Its just a A(ction)VC... :)

Comment: Yes, Struts2 is MVC. I would recommend that you pick up a good book on Struts2, since you have so many questions. http://www.manning.com/dbrown/

Comment: For what i know, the MODEL exist to manage my data to the server (that's i ever seen Bean scoped on JSF, for example). On struts2 i need to manage my data manually (like put an object to the session). So there isnt a big difference than other procedual languages. Like PHP. Maybe i wrong :) (i hope so..)

Comment: It is not true that you can't call two actions in one call, it is true however that it isn't in general a good idea. It's called action chaining (not recommended and typically seen as bad design) but when you call the first action it loads all its values onto the value stack and then it calls the next action and adds all its values to the value stack.